# Laravel 5.0 Code Completion in PHPStorm

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I tried most of thing and did exactly like larval-ide-helper but getting issue while code completion. please have a look screenshot.

[image]

When i use \Redirect in Code it working but not fully and if i use direct Redirect then here is screen :

[image]

Any one know what i missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you should look at gist https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822

Just download under your project root and restart you IDE.

From https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Update

And also take a look on video by Jef:

https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/15

**Update About Namespace in Laravel 5:**

The Redirect facade is not in the current namespace. So you either prepend it with :

`return \Redirect::something();`

Or add this at the top of your controller file:

`use Redirect;`

Comment: It's saying : An helper file for Laravel 4 and May see i posted title as Laravel 5.0

Comment: In laravel 5 everythings handling through  namespaces, so its mean we need to use specific namespaces by Use method in top of class to use without `\\` for any Facad.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to delete and create again maybe have some issue as IDE Showing Multiple Deceleration

Comment: Thats great, Any time. if you found this answer helpfull give thumbs up.